# Export DDL to place on server

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, spool

I want to write SQL procedure which writes file with DDL commands from certain schema to directorium on server. I done that using spool command and save it locally but I need it on server every time I ran it.
I am using Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: Have you tried with `UTL_FILE` ?

Comment: you can create a shell script which executes your procedure and then moves the newly created file to the server where you want to place it

Comment: Are you sure you're not re-inventing DataPump with the `content=metadata_only` option?

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_METADATA can be your friend. Using its procedure GET_DDL() can give you DDL scripts. You can use UTL_FILE to write it into a "Oracle DB directory" (this is exact Oracle object).

Or you can use an external script to connect to DB, using DBMS_METADATA to get you a DDL.

In these cases you need to script it with selecting USER_OBJECTS (or all/dba objects), etc.

Or you can use 3rd party tools like eg. Oraschemadoc is.

Answer (score 0):

This will export ddl of all object in current schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl_import
    IS
        file_ctl UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
        CURSOR object_cv IS
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE FROM USER_OBJECTS;
        code VARCHAR2(10000);
    BEGIN
        FOR cur in object_cv
        LOOP
            file_ctl:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ORADIR',cur.object_name||'.sql','W');
            code:=DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(CUR.OBJECT_TYPE,CUR.OBJECT_NAME,'ORATUT');
            UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_ctl,code);
            UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_ctl);
        END LOOP;
    END ddl_import;
```

**But before you compile and execute this procedure make sure you have done following things in step.**

**STEP1 :** Create directory in host(OS) environment and grant READ/WRITE to oracle user.

**STEP2:** Execute CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ORADIR AS ‘D:/dir_name’; dir_name is name of the directory which you have created in step1.

**STEP3:** Ask your DBA to grant you execute permission on UTL_FILE. Or if you have credentials of DBA then execute following- GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO user_name; user_name will be of course you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Here is description how to extract ddl for schema. [Extract whole schema](http://www.remote-dba.net/t_advanced_extract_schema.htm)

We have to change

```
-- add 
dest_clob clob; 
-- change
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DDL); 
    to 
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND (dest_clob, DDL);
```

at the end

```
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(dest_clob,dest_directory, my_schema.sql)
```

dest_directory is [Oracle Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm) with read/write privileges